# Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument, domxpath

i am getting wordpress active theme and then header.php of that theme through that code.

```
 $theme  = wp_get_theme();
 $header = get_header($theme);
```

and i echo $header i display perfectly,now i provide that $header to domDocument

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($header);
```

this code giving error

```
 Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input
```

i have also tried this code but does not effect any help?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrorsState = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($header);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrorsState);
```

or better way to add link in theme header.php through DomDocument????

Comment: Where you can see Fatal Error?  You have only Warning.

Comment: Have you tried `$doc->loadHTML(get_header($theme));`

Comment: yes i have but same issue.

Comment: You need just HTML that will go in `loadHTML`. your `header.php` can contain various functions etc. Just fetch your site with `file_get_contents('your-url.here')` then when you load it with `loadHTML` just pick the header with `$doc->getElementsByTagName( 'head' )`.